# SQL Server HashBytes Function

Tags: sql-server, function, hashbytes

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting different answers for the following:

Here is a very simple function used to return the hash Value:

```
CREATE Function [fn_GetPin](@strText VARCHAR(254))
RETURNS VARCHAR(254)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @strText = HashBytes('MD5', @strText);
    RETURN @strText;
END
```

Here is my SQL that returns 2 different values:

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', '7690') as Hash1
        , dbo.fn_GetPin('7690') AS Hash2
```

Results:

```
Hash1   Hash2
0xC6776F93BC9AFE2E511A1DBD5478362C  Æwo“¼šþ.Q½Tx6,
```

For some reason the function is not returning the same value as HASH1.
I'm just not sure why.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Accepted answer is below, I just added (max) to the VARBINARY to return the whole value. Thanks All.

```
CREATE Function [fn_GetPin](@strText VARCHAR(254))
RETURNS VARBINARY(max)
AS
BEGIN
    Return HashBytes('MD5', @strText);
END
```

Comment: I think this is because the function HashBytes returns varbinary and your (presumably interactive?) result is a bit of hex. Your function forces the return of varchar so it's showing you the binary blob interpreted as a string.

Comment: Little thing, but MD5 isn't a recommended hash algorithm for what you look like you're doing any more (and ideally the hash would be salted as well). Try SHA1 if you're running on <2012, or SHA2_256 or SHA2_512 otherwise. Have a look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2988/understanding-the-sql-server-hashbytes-hashing-algorithms/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks @eftpotrm I was using MD5 just for testing purposes. Turns out we are using SHA1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE Function [fn_GetPin](@strText VARCHAR(254))
RETURNS VARBINARY
AS
BEGIN
    Return HashBytes('MD5', @strText);
END
```

function should return a `varbinary` value.

Answer (score 1):

pvg pretty much nailed it above.

```
CREATE Function [fn_GetPin](@strText VARCHAR(254))
RETURNS VARBINARY
AS
BEGIN
    SET @strText = HashBytes('MD5', @strText);
    RETURN CAST(@strText as VARBINARY);
END
```